# What happens when $y=4x^2$ and $y=8x^2$ is multiplied?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When parabolicfunctions mentioned above are added, we get a new function with equation $y=12x^2$. But when we multiply these two function what is the result? 
Please explain by drawing graphs.

Comment: You'll get a function $y=32x^4.$

Comment: @Michael is it that simple? I am told that the function will have values over all four quadrants not only first and second.

Comment: No, $32x^4$ is always positive. The graph looks very much like a parabola, but narrower.

Comment: No, the graph of this function placed in the first and in the second quadrants.

Answer (score 2):

> But when we multiply these two function what is the result?

Then you no longer get a parabola, but a *similar* graph in the sense that the properties of all the graphs of the form $y=ax^{2n}$ (even powers) are similar (see remark below). The function would be:
$$y = 4x^2 \cdot 8x^2 =4\cdot 8\;x^{2+2} = 32x^4$$

> Please explain by drawing graphs.

Take a [look](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7B4x%5E2,8x%5E2,12x%5E2,32x%5E4%7D%20from%20-1%20to%201).

---

To get an idea of how the (even) exponent influences the graph, take a look at the [graphs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7Bx%5E2,x%5E4,x%5E6%7D%20from%20-1.5%20to%201.5) of the functions $x^2,x^4,x^6$ (ignoring coefficients, they only scale) and note that the higher the exponent, the *flatter* the graph for $x \in [-1,1]$ and the *steeper* outside of that interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a graph of (pretty much any) function you can think of, try [this calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bsjo0ptfva) out. I put the functions you were talking about in for you already.

I think the stumbling point for you here is that "paraboloids" are just setting $y$ equal to expressions in terms of a variable $x$, and that anything you can do to a number can be done to these expressions with equal validity.